# Skip payment PayPal recurring payments API

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to suspend a PayPal recurring payment profile such that it skips a month's bill?  If I suspend a payment, wait a month, then resume it - will it try to bill for the missed month?

As part of a proposed affiliate scheme we intend to skip a month's payment as a kick-back.  Is there any way to do this without getting the customer to submit a new paypal payment request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine. Ensure you set AUTOBILLOUTAMT to 'NoAutoBill' with the UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile API, though. This will stop it from adding an outstanding balance to the next bill. You could also set OUTSTANDINGAMT to 0 to remove any outstanding amount.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/